# How we click the button having same class name and same name

Tags: java, html, css, selenium, xpath

How we click the button having same class name and same name for different element other than using xpath method.

```
input class="btnstyle greenbtn paddinglr20" type="submit" value="Upload " name="submit_upload
```

I tried this for second button but not working,

```
WebElement butttonToClick1 = driver.findElement(By.name("submit_upload"));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[1].click();",butttonToClick1 );
```

Comment: We can't help you without the html

Comment: is the type and value is also same in another button?

Comment: How is this question different than [the one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35310893/how-can-i-click-the-second-submit-button-with-selenium-webdriver) you asked yesterday?

Answer (score 0):

> Selenium WebDriver API supports different possibilities to identify
>   elements: by ID, by CLASS, by NAME, by CSS selector, by XPath, by TAG
>   name. Also you define your custom selector in order to interact with
>   the elements.

It’s always a good practice to assign unique IDs to elements, also names and classes in order to be more usable for automatic UI tests. If that is not possible you’ll need to use advanced or XPath selector to interact with those elements. The most popular selectors are the CSS selectors due to performance and simplicity reasons.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("element id"))
driver.findElement(By.className("element class"))
driver.findElement(By.name("element name"))
driver.findElement(By.tagName("element html tag name"))
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("css selector"))
driver.findElement(By.link("link text"))
driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath expression"))
```

If there is uniqueness issue then you can also take `DOM` structure and generate `xpath`. It is up to you how optimize and improve element for locating purpose. If you found any one of above suitable to your condition then you can use it.

You can find more functions of `xpath` from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

@Senthil You can access through xpath and with xpath you can access 2nd element.
It always clicks the first one because findElement will return the first one found matching your criteria. You could use findElements to return a list of all the elements that match, then access the second one found. You could also use a xpath such as "(//img[@id='email'])[2]".

One thing you might want to do is investigate if you could create an xpath that would take into account the drop down it should be associated with this way you can ensure that the image you are clicking is always the image for that particular dropdown. Difficulty of this depends on your application.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use xpath like below:-

```
//input[@class='btnstyle greenbtn paddinglr20'][2]
```

OR

You can use list as below:-

```
   int i=0;
   List<WebElement> allOptions = driver.findElements("Your Locator");
    for ( WebElement we: allOptions) { 
       i++;
       if(i==1)
       {
          we.click();
        }
    }
```

Hope it will help you :)