# How can I click the second submit button with Selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium

**Example**

For the first button:

```
<input class="btnstyle greenbtn paddinglr20" 
        type="submit"
        value="Upload " 
        name="submit_upload"/>
```

For the second button (also same name and etc):

```
<input class="btnstyle greenbtn paddinglr20" 
        type="submit" 
        value="Upload " 
        name="submit_upload"/>
```

I tried this:

```
List<WebElement> btn = driver.findElements(By.name("submit_upload"));
btn.get(1).click();
```

Comment: Use formatting for the code snippet. Also what language are you using? Also don't forget your grammar.

Comment: Provide `html` sample code for your issue

Comment: Are there other elements on the page that have the name "submit_upload"? Your code should work unless there are others.

Answer (score 0):

By name may not be specific enough in this case. You could try the CSS selector below. Are you use the button is visible and enabled when you are trying to click it?

```
List<WebElement> btn = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("input[name='submit_upload']"));
btn.get(1).click();
```